# Create Progress bar to monitor all queries refresh as a whole using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Can someone help me do this one below:

Everytime I refresh my workbook like this [Sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvZJY.png)

It should show the progress bar of what is the progress status of refreshing the workbook queries.

So technically it will replicate what this thing doing [Sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS7MK.png) but in a custom way like this [Sample3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgbPU.png)

Please help me on this one.
THanks.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBdRA.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I dont believe you can read the status of the query progression in VBA, unless you are looking for a pretend progress bar

Comment: I deleted the code that I tried yesterday because its causing overflow error. But I tried to loop on each queries and using the AfterRefresh() events.

Comment: So what is the progress bar doing ? 25% complete after 1 query, 50% after two queries, etc?  Or showing the progression within each query?

Comment: This one "25% complete after 1 query, 50% after two queries, etc?".